# Append New line character to a snowflake row based on conditions

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake with a single column which is record from a file present in azure blob container

consider this record as below:

"123||snowflake||sample||record||from_stage||without||getting_splitted||by_field_delimitter||into_deifferent_columns"

Now there is a condition that if

length of entire record - length of record when each '|'(single pipe) is replaced by empty string '' >=38,Then

It should append \n before the record , so output should look like

Row 1: \n(blank line)
Row2:"123||snowflake||sample||record||from_stage||without||getting_splitted||by_field_delimitter||into_deifferent_columns"
note : this is sample record, any help is appreciated

Another input : 13||sample_col||help||test||col4||col5||col6||col7||col8||col9||col_10||something||||||||nothing||omg||||mii|| error: yes it is very tricky||Your time is pending please

output :

Row 1 : \n

Row 2 : 13||sample_col||help||test||col4||col5||col6||col7||col8||col9||col_10||something||||||||nothing||omg||||mii|| error: yes it is very tricky||Your time is pending please

Comment: What do you mean by "Before the record". A table has no ordering. Is there a column that establishes order? Please share more information.

Comment: May want to provide more sample data and desired output, assuming you have multiple scenarios rather than just that one.

Comment: before the record means this:

If input_record is this : "This is one row"

then output row should be :

Row 1 : \n (newline charcter)
Row 2 : "This is one row"

I have tried several ways but it is appending within the record, its not splitting the record into two lines

Comment: @PriyaChauhan This sounds like an XY problem. Certainly you don't want an arbitrary number of records in your table with a new line character, and only a new line character? Of course if you wanted to change the text value to append a new line character you could do: case when length(replace(some_text,'|','')) >= 38 then CHR(10) || some_text else some_text end . But that feels like you are trying to do something in the database that is best left to a presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

this is beyond gross, but if you want it, lets help:

Firstly I read two ways of you question, one is you want an actual table row:

```
with fake_data(record) as (
    select * from values
        ('123||snowflake||sample||record||from_stage||without||getting_splitted||by_field_delimitter||into_deifferent_columns'), 
        ('13||sample_col||help||test||col4||col5||col6||col7||col8||col9||col_10||something||||||||nothing||omg||||mii|| error: yes it is very tricky||Your time is pending please') 
), enriched as (
    select 
        seq8() as seq
        ,length(record) as rec_len
        ,length(replace(record,'|','')) as rep_len
        ,rec_len - rep_len as len
        ,record
    from fake_data
), injected as (
    select (e.seq * 2)+1 as seq
        ,e.record
    from enriched as e
    
    union all 
    
    select (e.seq * 2)+0 as seq
        ,'\n' as record
    from enriched as e
    where e.len >= 38
)
select record
from injected 
order by seq;
```

[image]

the other you just want the record altered, and the newline will

```
with fake_data(record) as (
    select * from values
        ('123||snowflake||sample||record||from_stage||without||getting_splitted||by_field_delimitter||into_deifferent_columns'), 
        ('13||sample_col||help||test||col4||col5||col6||col7||col8||col9||col_10||something||||||||nothing||omg||||mii|| error: yes it is very tricky||Your time is pending please') 
)
select 
    iff(length(record) - length(replace(record,'|','')) >= 38, '\n', '' ) || record
from fake_data
```

which inserts extra newline's into the output record, and thus you printing layer can handle later:

[image]

Then there is the "single pipe" implying double pipes should be ignored, aka don't replace escaped pipes...which normally involves negative lookahead regex's which snowflake does not current support. So you then have to hand build them via rewriting the escaped escape token ( double pipe) into into something else, then replace single pipes, and then replace back in the double pipes, and not "corrupt" the string. BUT given you are just measuring the length. we can change double pipe to double aa, replace all pipes with space, and count length.

```
with fake_data(record) as (
    select * from values
        ('123||snowflake||sample||record||from_stage||without||getting_splitted||by_field_delimitter||into_deifferent_columns'), 
        ('13||sample_col||help||test||col4||col5||col6||col7||col8||col9||col_10||something||||||||nothing||omg||||mii|| error: yes it is very tricky||Your time is pending please'),
        ('A|A')
)
select 
    record
    ,replace(record, '||', 'aa') as pipe_safe
    ,replace(record, '|', '') as r_rec
    ,replace(pipe_safe, '|', '') as r_pipe_safe   
    ,len(record)
    ,len(r_rec) 
    ,len(r_pipe_safe)
from fake_data
```

[image]

so here we see the `||` where changed to `aa` thus only the third example has a  single pipe replaced, thus the 3 -> 2